# В каком формате должна быть запись в wp_posts > post_name?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть задача, добавлять новые записи напрямую в базу WordPress.
Для этого создал в отдельном файле подключение к базе и выполняю запрос на добавление новой записи в таблицу `wp_posts`

Заметил что в ячейке **post_name** запись вида:

> %d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8

Я предположил что это заголовок статьи в **urlencode()** , вышло очень похоже - однако, видимо не совсем то. Так как после перехода на эту статью - выдает ошибку, ничего не найдено.

После этого я скопировал значение ячейки post_name из записи которая была добавлена через админку WordPress, и перешел на запись которая добавлена напрямую через мой скрипт - и она отобразилась.

Answer (score 0):

Это slug записи, проще говоря алиас. Его можно раскодировать, используя функцию `urldecode()`. Конкретно в вашем случае:

```
echo urldecode("%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8");
```

выдаст "тестирование-записи"

Закодировать можно, как вы уже сказали, `urlencode()`

По поводу переходов - проверяйте, правильно ли вбит slug в адресную строку.